# CRASH on Android 12 while using Huawei app service dependency, with build tools 31

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

We have implementation of

```
"com.huawei.hms:appservice:$huaweiAppService" WHERE huaweiAppService = '6.1.0.301'
```

And there is a crash:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
    at com.huawei.hms.api.b.getErrPendingIntent(HuaweiApiAvailabilityImpl.java:10)
    at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.BaseHmsClient.resolution(BaseHmsClient.java:3)
    at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.BaseHmsClient.checkAvailabilityAndConnect(BaseHmsClient.java:34)
    at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.BaseHmsClient.connect(BaseHmsClient.java:1)
    at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager$ConnectionManager.connect(HuaweiApiManager.java:21)
    at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager$ConnectionManager.sendRequest(HuaweiApiManager.java:24)
    at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager.connectAndSendRequest(HuaweiApiManager.java:8)
    at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager.handleMessage(HuaweiApiManager.java:7)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

I noticed that some Huawei services already have updates related with issue. So I'm asking about appservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback, this issue is a known issue. The R&D team will release a new fixed version in ***mid-November***, and I'll update this answer and let you know when it's released.

Answer (score 1):

Problem temporary solved by adding **huaweiBase** **transition dependency** along with appService dependency.

It's updated some source of appServiceLibrary under the hood and it's looks like temporary fix. In near future I will remove this base dependency and just updated appService to newer.

```
huaweiBase = '6.2.0.300'
huaweiAppService = '6.1.0.301'

huaweiDependencies = [
      huaweiBase: "com.huawei.hms:base:$huaweiBase",
      appService: "com.huawei.hms:appservice:$huaweiAppService"
]

    
implementation huaweiDependencies.huaweiBase
implementation huaweiDependencies.appService
```